# Inheritance with Overloaded Functions That Rely on Pure Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, pure-virtual

I have a base `Write` class that has a pure virtual function `write (std::string text)` that requires all derived classes to implement it.  In the base class, there is an overloaded `write` function that takes in an `int` and calls the pure virtual `write()`.

In the derived class, we implement the `write (std::string text)`, as required.

In the main, I'm able to call `console.write("dog\n");`, but I'm not able to call it with the overloaded version that takes in an int without going through the base class name `Write`.  Is there anyway to define this inheritance so that both `write` functions, one that takes in a `std::string` and one that takes in an `int` without giving away the details of the inheritance by going through the `Write` class name, as shown on the last line of the program?

I don't want the user to be able to call the overloaded `write(int)' through the`Write` class name, if possible.

```
#include <iostream>

class Write
{
protected:
    virtual void write (const std::string &text) = 0;

public:
    void write (const int &number)
    {
        write (std::to_string (number));
    }
};

class Console_Write : public Write
{
public:
    void write (const std::string &text) override
    {
        std::cout << text;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Console_Write console;
    console.write("dog\n");
    console.Write::write (1); // Is it possible to be able to change the inheritance so we can just call: console.write (1);
}
```

Comment: In the definition of `Console_Write`, add `using Write::write;`

Comment: This works and allows for us to directly call the overloaded `write` that takes in an `int`, however, nothing stops the user from calling it the way it currently written.  Is there a way to define the inheritance that prohibits the user of the `Console_Write` class from going through the `Write` class name?

Comment: You derive from `Write` publicly, modeling *is-a* relationship. You can't do that "without giving away the details of the inheritance" - `public` means public; they weren't kidding. `Console_Write` is-a `Write`; anything one can do with an instance of `Write`, one can do with `Console_Write` as well. That's the point of inheritance.

Comment: If you have combinations of public, nonvirtual and protected, virtual methods, the usual way is to not call them the same and thus bring overloading into the mix, too. For your case, you would often see them called `public write()` and `protected virtual do_write()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal pattern for this would be having your base class look something like:

```
class Write {
 public:
  virtual ~Write() = default;
  void write(const std::string& str) {
    write_internal(str);
  }
  void write(int n) {
    write(std::to_string(n));
  }
 private:
  virtual void write_internal(const std::string& str) = 0;
}

class ConsoleWrite : public Write {
 public:
  ~ConsoleWrite() = default;
 private:
  void write_internal(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << str;
  }
}
```

The pattern even has a name "Non-Virtual Interface" - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface has more information about the pattern.

Comment: I would have expected `write(int)` to dispatch to `write_internal()`. Why does it reuse the other public `write(string const&)` overload?

Comment: Great answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  My code above is just a super simplified example of the actual code I'm working on, but I implemented it just as you've demonstrated, while using @UlrichEckhardt 's suggestion.